# Maximum run time in Condor

Tags: condor

I'm using Condor to run many jobs, and I want to make sure that jobs don't run for more than a fixed amount of time, say 2 hours. Is there a way to specify in the Condor submission script that the job should be killed and marked as failed after this time limit?

Answer (score 4):

periodic_remove = (CommittedTime - CommittedSuspensionTime) > 7200

should do the trick. This would only work in the latest stable version. With the previous one you can get similar (though not the same) effect with:

periodic_remove = (RemoteWallClockTime - CumulativeSuspensionTime) > 60